# How to use sed with here-document?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to use a here-document with sed with a script.. but I get an weird error.

> sed: can't read Some random text.: No such file or directory

```
FILE=c:/output.file

read -r -d '' VAR <<"EOF"
Some random text.
EOF

./sed -f - "$VAR" > "$FILE" << SED_SCRIPT
s|text|word|g
s|Some|Lots of|g
SED_SCRIPT
```

Comment: `"$VAR"` is supposed to be a file but instead it's `Some random text`. It can't read a file named "Some random text" and so it's bombing out. You could echo your `$VAR` and pipe that to `sed` to do this. Or you could write `Some random text.` to a file and then use that file name in the same position as your `"$VAR"`, but you can't put text (even inside a variable) where a filename is expected.

Comment: You can also use a `here string` (besides the `echo` and file approximations).

Comment: If you tell us what your end goal is, we might be able to suggest an alternative to using what seems to be here-docs for both the sed commands and the text being operated on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a here document for the sed expression, you just use a parameter in quotes. You normally use the here document for the input.

```
    sed -e 's/text/word/g
s/Some/Lots of|g' <<EOF
Some random text.
EOF
```